Hi, unable to edit the existing Dailog in Mfc project , while creating the button on Dailog box its not showing any add variable o while right clik
Unable to open the button with double click for event handler in MFC dailog application .
In preexisting MFC project I want to customize other functionality but unable to access them .Even double click on any button is also not taking me to event handler option to modify it.

Clean the project, close it and delete all VS-generated files, like .clw, .pdb etc. After loading it, wait a little until VS rebuilds its files.
